# Compile only scss files

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

Is it possible to run only scss files on laravel mix?

I need to update only css info, and making the compiler run everything it takes long time.

Instead of doing always "npm run development", coul have another command running only scss files.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes You Can But:**

You will have to learn about webpack and mix first then you can handle this

**If you are working on vue.js then use**

```
npm run watch
```

You will not have to run it again and again only changes will be compiled wherever you made.

And read `package.json` it provides commands related to compiling assets.